# Error 0X8004005 - After upgrade DCs Windows Server

Tags: windows, active-directory

So I have the follow issues with administratives shares and unc paths by shares using hostname of pc, but working with ip.

I have 3 DCs with 2 diferent subnets, the one wich stop working as from a subnet starting with, 172.18. and others one as 172.16. the same as the share from "windows server 2003" wich is at subnet 172.16.

Users (at subnet 172.16.) can access the hostname, local users from subnet 172.18. can access subnet 172.16., but domain users are unable to access hostname from subnet 172.18. to 172.16., can open by IP.

The updates added to windows server 2012 r2 as:

[lastest updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXsDB.png)

after added, the hostname shares stop working from and some pcs.

In the subnet 172.16. for computer with that issue, I have needed add some change to gpo:

**Network security: LAN Manager authentication level:**
*

- Send LM & NTLM responses
- Send LM & NTLM - use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated

- 

one or other working.

DCs are in sync, have 3 distint nameservers. Time is sync,

That occured from PCs clients with windows 10 and 7. (no Win 11, used at that location)

The DC that are in subnet 172.18. is unable to open share (by hostname) to subnet 172.16.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-error-0x80004005-9acfca89-b5e4-b976-6fa1-ef358450f3ac So Microsoft says the error is about *Adobe Flash Player in Internet Explorer in Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 20212 R2, Windows 10 and Windows 10 version 1511 as well as Adobe Flash Player in Microsoft Edge in Windows 10 and Windows 10 version 1511* and although not mentioned probably because out of support it should apply to Win7 as well. It seems you have a Swiss cheese of security holes.

Comment: As I have say, my question as with shared folder, and not with IE or Flash

Comment: Sorry but the question is very unclear. What Win Server OS(s) do you have - only Server 2003? You have one server in 172.18 which has the problem, in 172.16 which do not have the problem, or...? Where exactly do you see this error - clients or the server? When exactly does it come  up? There's a lot of possible reasons for Error 0X8004005 so which solutions have you tried to resolve this so far? What's the exact, complete error message? What does Event Log show? ... and so on. I'd suggest asking a new question. Please check the Asking-section in [Help](https://superuser.com/help) first.